# Javascript - poor performance in V8 of functions added to String.prototype?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, v8

I've been using some code to extract unsigned 16 bit values from a string.

I discovered that adding this function to the prototype for `String`:

```
String.prototype.UInt16 = function(n) {
    return this.charCodeAt(n) + 256 * this.charCodeAt(n + 1);
};
```

is much slower than just having a function which takes a `String` as a parameter:

```
var UInt16 = function(s, n) {
    return s.charCodeAt(n) + 256 * s.charCodeAt(n + 1);
};
```

In Firefox the difference is only a factor of two, but in Chrome 15 it's *one hundred* times slower!

See results at http://jsperf.com/string-to-uint16

Can anyone proffer an explanation for this, and/or offer an alternative way of using the prototype without the performance hit?

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/45d6dc32250c0ad3 may shed some light. It's a bit disheartening.

Comment: @CrescentFresh, see my answer, it's still a lot slower and not "within 1%" as claimed in the thread when using objects... Or maybe I'm doin it wrong?

Comment: @Esailija: I don't see the relation of your answer to the question. Your additions to the test cases simply show (as the google group discussion covers) that saving a reference to a `String` object yields faster results when calling prototyped methods on that object than calling the same method on a primitive. The fundamental problem the OP is trying to address has to do with implicit type coercion when boxing a primitive to an object repeatedly.

Comment: @CrescentFresh, just saying that even if the OP did what the thread adviced (I.E. convert to object before doing work), it would be still slow unlike what is claimed in the thread.
That is: converting to object will not really fix it, which is shown in my link. That's how it's related.

Comment: @Esailija: I see. The observation you make in your answer is a response more to the thread, not so much to the OP. The thread is a bit disheartening, because it does *not* provide an answer to "an alternative way of using the prototype without the performance hit?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing prototype from a primitive (because it's not an object) is much slower than accessing prototype from an object.

http://jsperf.com/string-to-uint16/2

10x faster in chrome and 2x faster in firefox for me.

Is there an actual bottleneck in using the prototype? It's still very fast if you don't need millions of ops per second. If you need, then just use a function.

Answer (score 0):

**Alnitak**, I made a quick jsperf [test](http://jsperf.com/string-to-uint16/10) (which I accidentally published), and it shows that prototypes to user types aren't slower. When considering how engines like V8 works, it makes sense that the Java compilation will behave much differently when adding code to built-in objects.